# How can i uncomment a XML tag in eggplant

Tags: eggplant

```
typetext controlkey,a
typetext controlkey,c
put remoteclipboard(5) as a tree into myTree
put item 4 of myTree into a
delete every occurrence of "<!--" from a
log a
```

My variable a will have a XML tag(commented) value, i am trying to uncomment the XMl tag.

Comment: my variable a will contain <!-- Replace the above key with the following keys to turn request header authentication where "xxx" is the Server Variable Name and is the NetworkIDType -->

Comment: What's happening when you run your code right now? Can't you just delete the other side of the XML comment just like to deleted the opening comment sign?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to do treat the XML as text when you remove the comments, rather than turning it into a tree. Use a pattern with the `delete` command as follows:

```
delete every occurrence of <"<!--" then some characters then "-->"> in myXml
```